# sympy nsolve with MatrixSymbol

Tags: matrix, sympy, equation, solver

I'd like to numerically solve an equation involving a MatrixSymbol. Here's a basic example:

```
import sympy as sy
v = sy.MatrixSymbol('v', 2, 1)
equation = (v - sy.Matrix([17, 23])).as_explicit()
```

I'd like something like:

```
sy.nsolve(equation, v, sy.Matrix([0,0]))
```

But because `nsolve` does not accept MatrixSymbols, I've made a cludgy workaround that gives the correct output of `Matrix([[17.0], [23.0]])`:

```
vx, vy = sy.symbols('v_x v_y')
sy.nsolve(equation.subs(v, sy.Matrix([vx, vy])), [vx, vy], [0,0])
```

Essentially, I've converted a MatrixSymbol to a matrix of Symbols to make `nsolve` happy.

Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Edit: the workaround can be simplified to:

```
vseq = sy.symbols('a b') #names must be distinct
sy.nsolve(equation.subs(v, sy.Matrix(vseq)), vseq, [0,0])
```

But there ought to be a cleaner way to convert a MatrixSymbol to a sequence of Symbols, or a way to avoid needing to do so in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way is to create a Matrix from `symarray`:

```
v = sy.Matrix(sy.symarray("v", (2,)))
equation = v - sy.Matrix([17, 23])
sy.nsolve(equation, v, [0, 0])
```

Here, `symarray` creates a (NumPy) array of symbols `[v_0, v_1]` which is then turned into a Matrix. One can also use `sy.symarray("v", (2, 1))` so it's a double array, but since SymPy's `Matrix` constructor is cool with 1D inputs, this is not necessary.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm not sure I can do exactly what you suggest because the actual `equation` I'm working with is constructed through a series of matrix substitutions. As far as I can tell, something like `v.subs(v,w)` works if `v` and `w` are MatrixSymbols but not if they are arrays of Symbols. But the line `varr = sy.Matrix(sy.symarray("v", (2,)))` is much nicer than the line `vseq = sy.symbols('a b')` that I had before.

Comment: Then it seems you'll have to replace MatrixSymbols with Matrix(symarray) prior to numeric evaluation. The root cause is that SymPy "prints" the equation into a Python lambda to be passed to a numeric solver, and `lamdba v[0, 0]: v[0, 0] - 17` is not valid Python. Arguably it's a SymPy bug; it should handle code-printing different in this case, like `lamdba v_0_0: v_0_0 - 17`

Comment: Yes, I'm now basically doing `sy.nsolve(equation.subs(v, varr), varr, [0,0])`.